# SVN merge from branch to trunk so that everything that is not in the branch is deleted from trunk

Tags: svn

I have a problem with mergeing in SVN which I am not even shure is reasonably solvable.

There is a trunk in SVN repo. Everyone commited to trunk until day X. After that someone was asked to make a branch and so he did. But the problem is that he didn't do it using SVN methods. Instead he made a new empty branch folder, checked this folder out, copied all trunk's contents to this folder using OS-s copy/paste and commited it.
So those files in this branch know nothing about trunk-s svn history.

Now, few months later there is a need to make this branch the new trunk. So I need to somehow merge all this branches files to trunk and at the same time delete all from trunk that is not in the branch.

Problem why I can't just delete trunk and make the branch a new trunk is that I am hoping to preserve svn history that comes from trunk and also the one that comes from branch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to go old-school and manually compare and merge the files. I'd use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) for this task.

If you just want to mirror your branch's files onto trunk (including removing those files in the latter that don't exist in the former), then you could use [rSync](http://rsync.samba.org/) or [RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx). There's also good-old [Xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx).

Obviously, don't copy over the branch's metadata which are stored in the `.svn` folder, and you'd have to manually SVN-Add the new files from the branch, and SVN-Delete the files marked missing in trunk because the mirroring had deleted them.

Hope this helps.